# Trouble with Angular HttpClient delete statement

Tags: angular

Here is my call to the delete method to the service from the component.

```
  constructor(private wos: WorkorderService) {}
  canceled(workOrder) {
    this.wos.deleteWorkOrder(workOrder);
  }
```

Here is the delete method on the service.ts file

```
 deleteWorkOrder(workOrder) {
   this.http.delete(this.BASE_URL + '/deleteworkorder/' + 
   workOrder.accountNumber).subscribe((response) => {
    console.log("deleted");
  })
}
```

And this is the error message I get on the console:

> ERROR Object { headers: {…}, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: null, ok: false, name: "HttpErrorResponse", message: "Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error", error: error }

The API works fine as I have tried the statement with Postman.
Please advise!

This is what I see on the network section of the browser:
[image]

Comment: You probably didn't setup CORS on your server, so the angular app may not send AJAX requests to the server. Google for CORS.

Comment: @JB Nizet, CORS is all setup. The get & post command works, it is just the delete not working

Comment: Have you looked in the network panel of the browser dev tools? Does the CORS config authorize DELETE requests?

Comment: @JB Nizet, ieditted the original post with the network log from the browser.

Comment: Is there an actual delete request being sent after this options request? Do you have an interceptor adding headers to the request?

Comment: Those are the only two delete requests been sent. Haven't added any interceptors.

Comment: What the screenshot shows is a single OPTIONS request. Is there any DELETE request visible after that one?

Comment: I don't see any DELETE requests after that.

Comment: How does that happen, Am I actually not doing the delete operation with the delete statement

Comment: Yes, you are, but the browser refuses to send it because it may not, according to the response to the pre-flight OPTIONS request. AFAIK, the `Allow: Delete` header should be `Access-Control-Allow-Methods: DELETE`.

Comment: Where would I add this, is it in the cors?

Comment: Somewhere, in the CORS configuration on your server, that is apprently incorrect.

Comment: Thanks JB Nizet, That worked.

Answer (score 1):

This issue has driven me crazy for quite a long time. Just in case it can help anybody, my problem was the version of the .NET Core SDK: I had the version 2.2.101 and I had to upgrade to the 2.2.104. Cheers!